# how do nopCommerce list pages in the footer from a theme

Tags: nopcommerce

I downloaded a theme off the NopCommerce site.  The footer list some basic pages but there are some missing.  For example: the "About us page"  I can see from the admin end that these are pages that you can change the text for but the new theme just doesnt have them.

Is there a way to turn on and off page visibility or do i have to edit the root layouts in the source code to display links for these pages?

Answer (score 0):

If your theme doesn't include a link to the page, there's a good chance you'll have to add to the HTML yourself. Fortunately, its not difficult at all.

This is where the About Us link is in the Default template
[\Views\Common\Footer.cshtml](https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Common/Footer.cshtml) (Line 19)

```
<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Topic", new {SeName = Html.GetTopicSeName("aboutus") })">@T("AboutUs")</a></li>
```

Paste that line into your downloaded theme's footer file to get the About Us link to show up. If your theme follows a similar file structure as NopCommerce's Default Template, the file you'll need to edit should be at
\Themes{your-downloaded-theme-name}\Views\Common\Footer.cshtml